# App crashing because NSArray objectforkey: Objective C

Tags: objective-c, json, parsing, httprequest

I am trying to parse some Json with Objective C.

My problem is that I am getting the correct json back but when I try parse some of the json my app crashes.

```
// i will use a code from connect to DB tutorial
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.ddproam.co.za/Central/Asset/AssetsWithSerial?Serial=S00000001"];

// to execute php code
NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

// to receive the returend value
NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Login response:%@",strResult);

NSError *error;
//parse out the json data
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataURL //1
                                                     options:kNilOptions
                                                       error:&error];

NSArray* defineJsonData = [json objectForKey:@"AssetDesc"]; //2

NSLog(@"value: %@", defineJsonData); //3
```

Here is my json:

```
[{"AssetID":1,"AssetName":"Asset 1","AssetDesc":"This is a manually inserted Asset","AssetTypeID":1,"AssetTypeDesc":"This is a manually inserted Asset Type"}]
```

I am trying to get the AssestName out of the string. I must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 5):

The whole thing is an array containing a dictionary, not a dictionary containing an array...
This is a very dirty way to get the value you want - you want to write something more safe than this. Try checking the type of class returned before you try to use it...

```
NSArray* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataURL //1
                                                options:kNilOptions
                                                  error:&error];

NSDictionary* defineJsonData = [json lastObject]; //2

NSLog(@"value: %@", [defineJsonData objectForKey:@"AssetDesc"]); //3
```

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing that up for me @Wain. Very helpful.